# Does binding to a service connect the client to a new service instance?

Tags: android, client, android-service

In Android if you were to bind to a service while there was already an instantiation of the service, would another service be instantiated or would the client bind to the existing instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is already running, the client will bind the existing service.

Tips: You can use the flag BIND_AUTO_CREATE on the [bindService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) call to avoid service instanciation